# Can I move Windows 8 Start menu hot corner?

Tags: start-menu, windows-8-preview, start-screen

I like my task bar vertical at the right edge of the screen. This puts the Windows button to the top-right corner, however not the windows hot corner. Is there any way to either move or disable the hot corner in desktop mode (or altogether)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in the Windows8 consumer preview. If you'd like to give feedback to Microsoft about features you'd like to see in the final release, post them here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/Connect/Feedback