# How to disable the Start menu hot corner (bottom-left) in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, start-menu, start-screen, hot-corner

In Windows 8/8.1, when you mouse to the bottom-left corner of a screen, the Start Menu hint appears, even if you are on a monitor without a taskbar, or in a fullscreen application.  How do you disable this behavior?

There are lots of resources about disabling the other corner/side elements, but no obvious answers to this one.  Other than "use this third party tool," which is an insufficient explanation.  There must be some kind of registry setting that is controlling this behavior.

Comment: I remember this bothering me in Win8.  I guess I totally forgot that this no longer happens for me in 8.1.  You are still having this problem with the 8.1 version?

Comment: @Iraedei Correct. I'm currently using Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/384142/can-i-move-windows-8-start-menu-hot-corner

Comment: @CalvinFisher I am seeing the issue now.  Following Techie's link I see that there is no known fix for this.  I will dig around the registry on my notebook and see if I can change this or break it. :D one of the two.

Comment: @Techie007 Thanks for the info and link.  I'll have to leave Microsoft a suggestion for making this a changeable thing.  This isn't going to stop me from messing with the registry though. :D

Comment: Did a third party app actually disable it?  "Classic Shell" would appear to do so, but in my experience it does not.

Comment: @Iraedei - I came across http://www.instantfundas.com/2012/08/disable-start-screen-and-hot-corners-in.html and tried adding a DisableBLCorner registry entry, but no luck.

Comment: I also came across http://support.myaxispoint.com/knowledgebase/articles/233923-disabling-windows-8-edge-gestures and tried creating a DisabledEdges registry entry set to 15 (0f), but no luck there either.

Comment: Hi Calvin, Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue using multiple monitors. The Lower Left corner is annoying. Please let me know if you found a way to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it. Download a free program called ClassicShell, which I did have this already. If you install everything it will also install an application called Settings for Classic Start Menu. Open this up and then at the bottom select All Settings, which you will then have more tabs. Click on the Windows 8 Settings tab. Select All for Disable Active Corners.

By the way I know exactly what you mean about the corners being critical for certain applications and that bottom left corner was always in the way. It is fixed now!

If this helps, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to limit access on the device, perhaps you'd be interested in the [Assigned Access](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/28/how-to-setup-assigned-access-in-windows-8-1-kiosk-mode.aspx) feature.  It blocks access to the Start Screen and a lot more.

Comment: I don't see anything in there about the hot corners. My issue personally is that I sometimes use applications that expect the full extent of the screen to be usable and clickable, which makes those hot corners very annoying. :)